# RoR "убивает" mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Товарищи, у меня возникает странная проблема при работе с RoR.

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
legal 
tests
id,ref,ref1
```

test.rb

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :legals
end
```

legal.rb

```
class Legal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :test
end
```

Запускаю сервер и после обращения к странице http://***********/tests служба mysql падает:

> Puma caught this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
>   /home/ruby/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/client.rb:87:in `connect'

Лечится остановкой сервака и запуском команды:

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Rails 5.0.0.1
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Если не сложно покажите ваш config/database.yml. Сообщите вашу операционную систему и посмотрите остается ли процесс mysqld после возникновения ошибки? Если Puma временно заменить на thin ситуация воспроизводится?

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: wtsadmin
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64

Comment: ps -aux|grep mysql
mysql     6114  1.0 25.2 1094956 126080 ?      Ssl  17:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
ruby      6159  0.0  0.1  14512   952 pts/2    S+   17:36   0:00 grep mysql
а после

Comment: ps -aux|grep mysql
root      6326  0.0  0.4  14896  2428 ?        Ss   17:37   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
ruby      6387  0.0  0.1  14512   920 pts/2    S+   17:37   0:00 grep mysql

Comment: а как пуму заменить?

Comment: В Gemfile замените puma на thin и выполните bunlde install

Comment: c thin вообще не запускается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему нашел.

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :legals
end
```

Заменить на

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :legal
end
```

Comment: Вообще странно, база падать не должна, вместо этого у вас просто не должна работать связь по ассоциации belongs_to.

Comment: вчера пол ночи бился с этим и путем проб и ошибок нашел проблему

Comment: Поздравляю! Вы действительно нашли ошибку и ответ верен (хотя обычно СУБД работает после таких ошибок работает штатно, возможно есть что-то еще в системе, что приводит к таким фатальным сбоям).

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема снова возникала в разных ситуациях. В итоге проверил наличие ошибок в логам Mysql (/var/log/mysql/):

```
 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
```

Лечение оказалось простым

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

Полностью описано тут:
http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html

Comment: Так и напишите -- добавили подкачку, а падало всё, потому что кончалась оперативная память и OOM killer прибивал MySQL.